# Difference between NCE-Loss and InfoNCE-Loss

Tags: loss-function, word-embeddings, word2vec, nlp, representation

I started looking into word2vec and was wondering what the connection/difference between the [NCE-Loss](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2013/file/db2b4182156b2f1f817860ac9f409ad7-Paper.pdf#cite.MnihTeh2012) and the [infoNCE-Loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03748.pdf) is. I get the basic idea of both.

I have a hard time deriving one from another, do you have any idea ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both NCE loss and InfoNCE loss use positive examples and sampled negative examples to contrast a true data distribution with a noise distribution. As a byproduct, you can learn something useful like $p(y|x)$ in the case of NCE, or high quality representations of your objects (e.g. documents, images, etc.) in the case of InfoNCE.

NCE casts the contrastive learning task as a binary classification problem, where we want to predict if a data point (a class and a context) came from the noise distribution or the true data distribution.

InfoNCE generalizes this idea and treats this task as a multiclass classification problem, where the goal is to predict which of the $N$ examples (1 positive and $N-1$ negatives) came from the true data distribution.

NCE uses the logistic function to generate probabilities, while InfoNCE generates probabilities from a calculation that looks more like softmax (i.e. $\frac{f(y, x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(y_i, x)}$). Once you have probabilities, you can apply cross-entropy loss to both.

Examining the loss for NCE and InfoNCE for a single example with 1 negative sample for both NCE and InfoNCE, we see that one loss function cannot easily be derived from the other. See [this blog post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-05-31-contrastive/#nce) for the loss functions.